# Get document library folder & files via client object model

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, document-library, client-object-model

I have a SharePoint Library and I want to traverse all folders, sub folders and files of it using client object model. How can this be done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use the below code to traverse a specified document library using client object model.

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("Your Site URL "))
            {
                List docList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Document Library Name");
                clientContext.Load(docList); CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
                camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'></View>";
                ListItemCollection listItems = docList.GetItems(camlQuery);
                clientContext.Load(listItems);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                foreach (ListItem listItem in listItems)
                Console.WriteLine("Id: {0} ", listItem.Id);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

The above code will traverse the specified document library's folders, Sub Folders and prints the item ID's. Before executing the code, please add reference to the following DLL's

```
1. Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll 
2. Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll
```

To display the folder and subfolder names and the item names inside the folder nd subfolder, use the below code

```
using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("Your site name"))
            {
                Web web = ctx.Web;
                ctx.Load(web);
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List docList = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Document library Name");
                ctx.Load(docList);
                CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
                camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'></View>";
                ListItemCollection listCol = docList.GetItems(camlQuery);
                ctx.Load(listCol);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem item in listCol)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("FileDirRef: {0}", item["FileDirRef"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("FileLeafRef: {0}", item["FileLeafRef"]);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
```

Comment: Hi Sakthi,
Now I have altered the code and tested. Its traversing all the folders and subfloders in a Library. Hope it might help you.